# Reduce size of Bitmap to some specified pixel in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I would like to reduce My Bitmap image size to maximum of 640px.  For example I have Bitmap image of size 1200 x 1200 px .. How can I reduce it to 640px.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you pass bitmap `width` and `height` then use:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int bitmapWidth, int bitmapHeight) {
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, true);
}
```

If you want to keep the bitmap ratio the same, but reduce it to a maximum side length, use:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. There is an error tough, you must check "if (bitmapRatio > 1)" not 0. Even if height is bigger, you will not have a negative ratio.

Comment: I see this solution everywhere. But why it crops my bitmap? I only have left top part and it is shifted to the right of screen as well(

Answer (score 13):

or you can do it like this:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);
```

Passing filter = false will result in a blocky, pixellated image.

Passing filter = true will give you smoother edges.

Comment: how can you use this method? This method doesn't exist!

Comment: Did you downvote?
What do you mean it doesn't exists? Bitmap.createScaledBitmap exists since api lvl 1

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code to reduce Bitmap image resolution (pixels) to desired value...**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageProcessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "ImageProcessActivity";
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/sdcard/DCIM/my_image.jpg";

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {

                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampleDrawableFromFile(String file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_process);

        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... objects) {

                try {

                    return decodeSampleDrawableFromFile(IMAGE_PATH, 640, 640);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

> Steps:
>
> 1. Get the `Bitmap.Options` (image info).
> 2. Sample the size to desired sample size.
> 3. Load to `Bitmap` with given options (desired resolution) from the image file into a `bitmap` object. But do this operation in a background thread.
> 4. Load `Bitmap` image into `ImageView` on UI thread (`onPostExecute()`).