# Compress photo quality in Android

Tags: android, jpeg, image-compression

I'm trying to compress a photo (.jpg) which is taken by the Android Camera.

For Example:
Compress

Image with

2048 x 1536, quality 90, 24bit depth

to

1024 x 768, quality 70, 24bit depth

Is there any library or something that can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android follow this link it will help you to compress your image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759195/reduce-size-of-bitmap-to-some-specified-pixel-in-android/15759464#15759464 follow this link for compress your image size

Answer (score 3):

you can equally do this to compress your bitmap image

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Here 100 is quality of image and you can change format of image to get low resolution image.