# How to clear the bitmaps when back is pressed (Java OOM error)?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My application uses many large images. Instead of requesting the use of native memory, I want to clear the bitmaps on back pressed. Android Manifest already states the required use of largeHeap so that's not an issue. The problem is the sheer amount of bitmaps. Can this be done using the back button?

I am getting the java out of memory error. The bitmap combined size exceeds the memory allocated even when largeHeap is enabled.

Update: Each activity has it's own bitmap. When the application reaches around 10 activities, 10 bitmaps, that's when the out of memory error is show.

Comment: Did you tried bitmap.recycle();??

Comment: @WISHY there are so many bitmaps the device won't even load all of them, let alone recycle.

Comment: Try to store the bitmap in cache and load from cache. And you can also try to reduce the size of bitmap....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759195/reduce-size-of-bitmap-to-some-specified-pixel-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try  `bitmap.recycle()` for all images you used before  you start new `activity` .

Comment: Will this work even if there are around 28 activities each with their own bitmap?

Comment: If you single activity is able to render the image successfully then yes recycle will works for you

Comment: That's the problem. The device can't render more than 10 and I need around 28 for recycle to be an effective solution. Can I clear some bitmaps using the back button after say 10 bitmaps and _then_ use bitmap.recycle(  );

Comment: Single Activity contains single image , and you have 10 activity which contains the same , right ?

Comment: No, there are 28 activities with 28 bitmaps and the device cannot render more than around 10 even with largeHeap enabled.

Comment: Ok then , Do bitmap.recycle() for current activity while you about to start new activity .

Comment: Could this be implemented using the back button as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74230/discussion-between-dhams-and-goooooogle).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SoftReference` to save the `Bitmap`. When the memory is not enough , GC will clear it or you can try to use the `bitmap.recycle()`.