# resize image picked from gallery

Tags: android, image, resize

I'm working in an app that take an image from the gallery and save it into parse.

The problem is that when I pick an image taken by the camera the size of the image is too big and takes some seconds to load the image in an image view. Also when I save the image and download again in the app it takes a lot of time because it has to download a big image.

I don't know how I reduce the size of the image picked. I tried several things but anything works.

This is my code at this moment

```
public class Datos extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private ImageButton imageView;


ParseFile file;
byte [] data;

/*
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    bm.recycle();
    return resizedBitmap;
    }
*/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);
    btnClick();

    imageView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


    ImageButton pickImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    pickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            //photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
            //photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
            //photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            //photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            //photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);


    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    data = stream.toByteArray();

                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedImage);
                    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bmp = drawable.getBitmap();
                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 120, 120, false);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

    }
}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                           long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    if (spinner.getId() == R.id.telefono) {
        consola = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    } else if (spinner.getId() == R.id.provincia) {
        provincia = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


public void btnClick() {

    Button buttonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);


    buttonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Storing image in parse passed in  onclick method of a button with the below code:


            Intent intentDatos = new Intent(Datos.this, Inicio.class);
            startActivity(intentDatos);


            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Musica");

            if (data != null) {

                file = new ParseFile("selected.png", data);
            }

            else {

                data = "".getBytes();
                file = new ParseFile("selected.png", data);
            }

            //file.saveInBackground();


            testObject.put("imagen", file);

            testObject.saveInBackground();




        }
    });


}
```

Does Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce size of Bitmap to some specified pixel in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759195/reduce-size-of-bitmap-to-some-specified-pixel-in-android)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759464/1529129) will help you

> if you want bitmap ratio same and reduce bitmap size. then pass your
>   maximum size bitmap. you can use this function
>
> ```
> public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
>         int width = image.getWidth();
>         int height = image.getHeight();
>
>         float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
>         if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
>             width = maxSize;
>             height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
>         } else {
>             height = maxSize;
>             width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
>         }
>         return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
> }
> ```

change your `onActivityResult` in `SELECT_PHOTO` case like this:

```
   case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 400);// 400 is for example, replace with desired size

                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your answer but the problem is that I don't exactly know where to use this part of code. I have been trying but it doesn't work. "getResizeBitmap" appears with message never used. Could you help me with this or send me an example about how to use this code? I have looked for.

Comment: Great! works perfectly while BitmapFactory.decodeFile() fails