# How reduce size of image raw?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-resizing

I'm creating an app on android that uses a fingerprint reader, the problem is that the images are in real time, with dimensions of 800x750 and with a byte array size of 600000, when converting it to bitmap and assigning it At the imageview, the app is too encouraging and crashing.
how can I reduce the size of that array of bytes that is a raw image so that my application can draw fingerprints without problems

```
imagePreview.setImageBitmap(imageData.toBitmap());
```

I tried this but it's still slow

```
Bitmap bmp = imageData.toBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        options.inSampleSize = 2;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length,options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If you're using ARGB_8888, the image will take 4*width*height bytes in memory.  There is no way to reduce that.  If you're having problems, look for memory leaks, and consider caching.

Answer (score 0):

[This Answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800400)

**if you want bitmap ratio same and reduce bitmap size. then pass your maximum 
size bitmap.**

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
 }
```